# ArcGis 10.1 - .NET Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, arcgis

**Background:**

.NET Framework 2.0, C#
ESRI ArcGis 10.1
64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2.

1. We have a thirdparty program (System A for simplicity) using ESRI-components running a custom Model-system for Maps.
2. System A  also uses it own licensing system.
3. We are pulling data from System A to the web for users to view.
4. The system as it follows:
   Web <-> WebService (using .NET-Remoting 2.0) <-> WindowsService.exe <-> DataFetcherStub.dll <-> DataFetcher.dll <-> System A

**Problem:**

Running this on ArcGIS 9.3 up to ArcGIS 10.0 have been no problem and earlier version of System A.

The providers of System A currently upgraded this to ArcGIS 10.1, using .NET-interop from 10.0.
We did that also, but now it will not work using the .NET-Remoting -> WindowsService any more.

Running an EXE using the DataFetcherStub everything is ok.
Running the windows service it crashes within the System A.

```
Faulting application name: windows_service.exe, version: 1.0.4802.40962, time stamp: 0x51293874
Faulting module name: AfCore_libFNP.dll_unloaded, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4f920360
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x619fe9b0
Faulting process id: 0x14c0
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce120f632c1f0e
Faulting application path: D:\path\windows_service.exe
Faulting module path: AfCore_libFNP.dll
Report Id: a41b42dc-7e02-11e2-8e56-00155d0a11a9
```

Have anyone come up with this error when having licensing with ArcGIS and running through a windows service?

There is a thread on ESRI-forums, but it wont leave me any clues how to solve this?

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/74546-Product-Licensing-in-Scheduled-Batch

Approaching the vendor is not an option as it took them nearly a year to fix the last problem we discovered. Pointing the finger at us for 9 months before they finally got the proof that it was their bug, and i am pretty sure they will fight this also. It is quicker if we can do a work-around.

**I have tried doing this from the windows-service.**

1) System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => FireAndForgetProcess()); NO LUCK

2) Process.Start("FireAndForgetMe.exe") NO LUCK

Anyone can give another approach to get external exe to "release itself" from the windows service and act as if it started by it own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I changed the account that are running the windows-service to my admin-account, and now it works. Either 10.1 demands more of the windows-account running the service, or they have downgraded the account.

I guess i have to check that in the morning. Problem solved however.

EDIT: It is the rights of the accounts that need to be raised after 10.1.

Answer (score 1):

The Esri development team gave me a fix without having to run using an admin account.

The issue here is that the FLEXnet Licensing Service (which Esri now uses at 10.1, but was not used in 10.0) doesn’t have the proper execution permissions set to it such that the “Network Service” account can start it.

Esri working on a patch, but in the meantime, there is a manual workaround:

1. Ensure that you are logged in as a user with administration privileges on the machine.
2. From the windows Start menu, select run and enter ‘cmd’. Right-click on “cmd.exe” and select “Run as Administrator.”
3. In the command prompt, run the following command:
   sc sdshow "FLEXnet Licensing Service"

This will print out the DACL permissions that are registered with that service:
D:(D;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;NU)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)(A;;CCLCSWRPLOCRRC;;;IU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)

We need to insert “(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;WD)” into the permission string, such that it becomes:
D:(D;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;NU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;WD)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)(A;;CCLCSWRPLOCRRC;;;IU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
NOTE:  The user’s DACL string may vary, and edits to the string should be done carefully.

1. To register the DACL with the service run the command:
   sc sdset "FLEXnet Licensing Service" ${your original DACL string with the new permission string inserted}

For the example above you would enter:
sc sdset "FLEXnet Licensing Service" D:(D;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;NU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;WD)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)(A;;CCLCSWRPLOCRRC;;;IU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)

1. You should see a [SC] SetServiceObjectSecurity SUCCESS. That's it. Network Service should now run without error.